# Why write Value in Eval Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

if we write only "Value" in Eval() function like Eval("Value") what does it mean?
I mean there is no item there with name Value to Bind so why we are using "Value".
Note I am Working in ASP.Net Using C#. | Visual Studio 2012

HTML:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = files;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are getting the value of a property named "Value" from the object being bound. In your case you are binding a list of `ListItem` objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value(v=vs.110).aspx